# Почему не получается отправить сообщение telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

client = TelegramClient(session,
                    api_id,
                    api_hash
                    )
async def main():
    await client.send_message('username', 'Hello to myself!')

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Простенький код, по идее должен работать и отправлять сообщение, но это не так.

на выходе выводит:

```
Server sent a very new message with ID 7161122737890074629, ignoring
Server sent a very new message with ID 7161122738048177153, ignoring
```

Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут стоит обратить внимание не на код, а на ошибку, которая возникает:

```
Server sent a very new message with ID 7161122737890074629, ignoring
Server sent a very new message with ID 7161122738048177153, ignoring
```

Эта ошибка означает, что происходит попытка зайти в аккаунт с не правильной сессией(она не валидна).
Суть в том, что до этого, я пытался открыть файл .session, с помощью блокнота. И в по итогу этот файл стал открываться только через блокнот. И при попытке открыть эту сессию, скрипт ловит ошибку. Как исправить? Обнуляйте вход через блокнот у файлов с расширением .session, и все будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отправить сообщение самому себе нужно в username вписать 'me'

```
username = 'me'
await client.send_message(username, 'Hello to myself!')
```

Чтобы отправить сообщение пользователю нужно его номер или @юзернейм также вписать в username

```
username = '@юзернейм взятый из профиля цели (друга/папы итд)'
    await client.send_message(username, 'Hello to myself!')
```